# Semantic UI Grid Classes

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

In most CSS frameworks grid classes are clearly defined for example Bootstrap has

```
xs (for phones)
sm (for tablets)
md (for desktops)
lg (for larger desktops)
```

Reading through Semantic UI it does not seem to have to grid class, does anybody know what they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantic ui do have grid classes , they are explained [here](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html).

However what you are refering to is the sizes that are controlled by [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Media queries are ways to selectively apply some rule based on the device specification.

If we look at bootstrap code we see things like :

```
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .visible-xs {
      display: block !important;
    }
    table.visible-xs {
      display: table !important;
    }
    tr.visible-xs {
      display: table-row !important;
    }
    th.visible-xs,
    td.visible-xs {
      display: table-cell !important;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .visible-xs-block {
      display: block !important;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .visible-xs-inline {
      display: inline !important;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .visible-xs-inline-block {
      display: inline-block !important;
    }
  }
```

These are media queries optionally showing components, now although semantic ui does not give you this explicit definition it does have this concern on it's components, for example [here](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/44a6bfa23b6e527bf50a353c209d3cbbfa58bcdb/dist/components/container.css#L42) semantic UI Apply the rules on the [containers](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/container.html) and you can use them for the same purpose:

> Containers are designed to responsively adjust their maximum width based on the size of the screen they are appearing.

Answer (score 0):

The grid system with semantic ui is not the same as the grid system with css Bootstrap.

You can learn more about Semantic UI here: https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html

Here is an example of Semantic UI grid being utilized in a React application:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className=“ui container grid”>
    <div className=“ui row”>
       <div className=“column eight wide”>
         <SongList />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I now have three nested divs with a `className` of `ui container grid`, `ui row`, and `column eight wide`.